# Reporting Services Grouping

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm new in Reporting services and got little confused.
in the screen shot you can see what I did.

[Link to Screen shot http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/8283/19206721.png](http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/8283/19206721.png)

I have two groups, the inner is by employe name, and the outer is by Month.
Now I want to calculate the sum of the hours for example and it doesn't works.

In the textbox with the value of 755.434 the formula is :

=Sum(Fields!time_difference.Value, "GetEmployeesOverTime")

I *think* (not sure) it calculates all the employees instead of only those who are above,
and I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
=Sum(Fields!time_difference.Value)
```

and it will sum over the group correctly (in this case, just for the employee).

Adding the data set's name takes the sum of the value over the entire data set as you have discovered. This is useful for calculating percentages, for example:

```
=Sum(Fields!time_diff.Value) / Sum(Fields!time_diff.Value, "GetEmployeesOverTime")
```

This would calculate the sum for this employee (that is, this group in your table) as a ratio of the entire firm (that is, the entire data set).